# cache each item or a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have a large number of items to cache. Would it be better to put each object instance in the cache alone or load them all into a collection and cache the collection?

Assume for the sake of argument that I dont care either way how it is done, I just want the best performance for accessing a specific item. If there are 10K of them I can have 10K entries in the cache or one entry that is a collection with 10K items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that caching each item individually would make it quicker to access an individual item.  you could simply request the specific item.  If the entire list is cached then the list would need to be loaded and then queried for the item.

Frankly, I'm guessing the performance gains would be minimal (unless you are caching large items and performing odd queries),